# jquery validate success event triggers each time a character is entered

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Recently i've been working on a new project and i decided to do the JavaScript form validation using jQuery validate plugin.

Unfortunately i encountered a problem it seems that each time i enter a character in the textbox,the success event gets triggered.

Have a look at my html form:-

```
<table id="tible">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <center>
            <label for="nom">Nom:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td >
         <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom"  placeholder="nom ici" required data-rule-required="true" style="width:200px;" data-msg-required="Veuillez entrer votre Nom" data-msg-success="cool"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <center>
            <label for="prenom">Prénom:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td  >
         <input type="text"  placeholder="pr&eacute;nom ici" name="prenom" required data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Veuillez entrer votre prénom(un seul suffit)" id="prenom" style="width:200px;"/>
      </td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <center>
            <label for="email">Email:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td >
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required data-rule-required="true" data-rule-email="true" placeholder="Email ici" data-msg-required="Veuillez entrez votre adresse Email " data-msg-email="Veuillez entrez une adresse Email valide" style="width:200px;"/>
      </td>
      <td class="td2">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <center>
            <label for="adresse">Adresse:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td >
         <input type="text" data-msg-required="Veuillez renseigner une adresse valide" data-rule-required="true" placeholder="Adresse ici" name="adresse" id="adresse" style="width:200px;"/>
      </td>
      <td class="td2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td >
         <center>
            <label for="tel1">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone 1:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text"  data-msg-required="Veuillez entrer un numéro de téléphone (mobile/fixe)"  data-rule-required="true" name="tel1" id="tel1" placeholder="Numéro principal ici" style="width:200px;"/>
      </td>
      <td class="td2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td >
         <center>
            <label for="tel2">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone 2:</label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td>    
         <input type="text" name="tel2" id="tel2" placeholder="Numéro secondaire ici" style="width:200px;"/>     
      </td>
      <td class="td2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <center>
            <label for="pays">Pays:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select name="pays" id="pays"  size="1" id="pays"  style="width:200px;" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Veuillez selectionner votre pays">
            <option  value="" selected>choisissez votre pays</option>
            <option  value="pays1"><?php echo 'Cote D\'ivoire'; ?></option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td class="td2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <center>
            <label for="ville">Ville:<em class="red">*</em></label>
         </center>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select name="ville" id="ville"  size="1" id="ville"  style="width:200px;"  data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Veuillez selectionner votre ville">
            <option  value="" selected>choisissez votre ville</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td class="td2"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div class="acceptance">
   <!--<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('inscription').submit()"  class="cusbtn" >Ok</a>--><input type="button" class="cusbtn" value="Ok" id="subinscrip"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('inscription').reset()" class="cusbtn" value="Annuler" />
</div>
<center>
   <p><em>" les champs ci-dessus contenant ce symbole <span class="red">*</span> sont &agrave; remplir obligatoirement. "</em></p>
</center>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery snippet that handles the validation

```
$("#inscription").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    success: function (label) {

        label.html("&nbsp;").removeClass('error');
        label.addClass('success');

    }

});

$('#subinscrip').click(function () {
    if ($("#inscription").valid()) {
        $("#inscription").submit();
    }

});
```

When i enter a character in the field `"nom"` for example it automatically shows the valid icon and if i keep on entering character,for each character entered after the first,it will create a new label with the valid icon and display it on multiple lines as shown in the following screenshot[image: problem 's screenshot]
how can i stop this from happening ? thanks

Comment: Question, do you only want it to validate the input on click, or do you want it to validate as the user types in the info (so as soon as the user makes a mistake they are notified)

If its the former, put it in the click event.

Either way, you can solve the issue with the multiple labels by adding the label once in the errorPlacement callback. You can either check if label exists and if not add it, or remove the label before adding it.

Comment: i want to validate the infos as the user types some info in.for the label problem can you give me a code sample to do that i just did but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `success` callback causing your problem but the `errorPlacement` callback function.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
},
```

You are telling it to `appendTo` every time it fires.  "Append" means that it gets "added" to what's already there.  `.insertAfter()` should be closer to what you need...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent().next());
},
```

You're using the `highlight` callback function backwards...

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
},
```

The `highlight` callback is what highlights the "errors".   However, your code is *removing* the `errorClass`, despite that the fact that this callback is fired only whenever there is an error.

Also, typically when using the `highlight` callback, one uses the `unhighlight` callback so that things will properly *toggle* when errors come and go.

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
},
```

Then you are incorrectly trying to toggle the two classes with `success`...

```
success: function (label) {
    label.html("&nbsp;").removeClass('error');
    label.addClass('success');
}
```

The `success` callback is what you use when you want to show the message `label` on a "valid" field.  Normally, the message `label` is hidden when the field is valid.  Instead, these classes should be toggled with the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions and `success` should only be used to handle the "valid" `label` content.

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass('success');
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass('success');
},
success: function (label) {
    label.html("&nbsp;");
}
```

And these two callbacks also take a third argument called `validClass` which will normally be the plugin's default "valid" class called `valid`.  Since yours is called `success`, you can change it to `success` with the `validClass` option...

```
validClass: "success",
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
},
```

And finally, if you fix all that and still want to disable validation on every keystroke, use this option...

```
onkeyup: false
```

Just remember to never set that option to `true` as it will break the default functionality.

**See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/**

Comment: thanks for your answer.unfortunately after updating the code it made things worse.i used the highlight that way because the error class background image(red circle with the x)  displays into the input fields as well as the td i use to display errors so when i use your code validClass: "success",
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
}, it does what i explained above

Comment: that is why i do it in the success. onkeyup helps me a bit but as soon as i leave the field and comes back into it if i press a key thte multiple labels problems pops up again

Comment: i think i have to check if a field has already been validated so that it stops appending.because i noticed that it checks on focus out even if the field is already filled with valid characters and it appends

Comment: i finally solved the multiple labels problem by emptying the html of the td i use to display the error messages thanks again sparkyfor pointing me in the right direction error placement was the place where i skrewed up